# Build pipeline to upload .jar package to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-lambda, continuous-integration, maven

So far according to the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html, the only way to upload .jar code to an AWS Lambda function would be to manually upload the file over their web interface.

Is there a way to upload the file in the Maven build or another pipeline?

Comment: I'm thinking whether I can make a Maven plugin, and bundle the AWS cli inside of it, not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Can you not use the [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/)? I'm using it to build Java lambdas and it works fine.

Comment: Right now we don't use AWS CLI, but I'll look into this